# Cannot seem to resize an <a> tag within a ul

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got an a tag nested inside of a `<ul> <li> </ul> </li>.`

Despite changing the element to

```
#Page_Container #Fixed_Navigation a {
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```

the height and width of the 's remain auto

I was thinking perhaps it is because JQuery SlideToggle changes the display of the element to list-item?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ELVmC/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#Page_Container #Fixed_Navigation a {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: It's just `display: block;`